# How to use box plot with column range

Tags: r, boxplot

I want to plot fee as a percentage of income `fee_per_inc` for each income `year_hh_inc` quintile.

this is what I have so far:

```
pacman::p_load(RCurl, plm, tibble, ggplot2, AER, dplyr, car, arm, broom, tidyr, fastDummies, dummies)


x <- getURL("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/dothemathonthatone/maps/master/main_test.csv")
    maindf <- read.csv(text = x, row.names=NULL)

maindf <- maindf %>% 
 mutate(category = cut(year_hh_inc, breaks = (quantile(year_hh_inc, c(0, 1 / 5, 2 / 5, 3 / 5, 4 / 5, 1), na.rm = TRUE)), labels = c("first_quint", "second_quint", "third_quint", 'fourth_quint', 'fifth_quint'), include.lowest = TRUE), vals = 1) %>% 
 pivot_wider(names_from = category, values_from = vals, values_fill = list(vals = 0))


box  <- boxplot(maindf$year_hh_inc ~ maindf$fee_per_inc, col = 3:5)
```

This is what I would like as an end result:

[image: Desired End Result]

I think I have a bit more work to do; any help from this point is appreciated.

Comment: Michael, I am getting `maindf$year_hh_inc` as a factor variable with 7 levels, not a numeric variable that you can `cut`. `Levels: -8 0,70 0,75 0.25 1 f-r_€ 20 f-r_income`

Comment: @AllanCameron Thank you for taking a look at the problem and informing on the data issue. I have just updated the table after wrangling with it and testing the result in a Jupyter Notebook terminal. It looks good now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there were a couple of problems here. You need the boxplot to have the variables the other way round. Also, you need to use the `category` variable that you created in mutate instead of the original variable. Lastly, you don't need the `pivot_wider`.

Some of the values were also way outside the useful range and may have been wrong (some numbers were -8), so I have trimmed the outliers to make the graph prettier. You'll want to check the original data to see whether this makes sense.

```r
pacman::p_load(RCurl, plm, tibble, ggplot2, AER, dplyr, car, arm, broom, tidyr, fastDummies, dummies)

x <- getURL("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/dothemathonthatone/maps/master/main_test.csv")
    maindf <- read.csv(text = x, row.names=NULL)

maindf <- maindf %>% 
 mutate(category = cut(year_hh_inc, 
                       breaks = (quantile(year_hh_inc, c(0, 1/5, 2/5, 3/5, 4/5, 1), na.rm = TRUE)), 
                       labels = c("first_quint", "second_quint", "third_quint",
                                  'fourth_quint', 'fifth_quint'), 
                       include.lowest = TRUE), 
        vals = 1) 

maindf <- maindf[maindf$fee_per_inc > 0 & maindf$fee_per_inc < 0.01, ]

box  <- boxplot(maindf$fee_per_inc ~ maindf$category, col = 3:5)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-03-03 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>